# Open multi-page TIF files in a Metro Win 8 application as an image source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-8, tiff

It's possible to set a TiF (or TIFF) file in a Metro Application as an Image source very easily...

```
Image imm = new Image();
imm.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filetiff_path));
```

The problem is that the content showed in the image is always the first page of the Tif  and i am not able to set the content to another pages of the source file.

In WPF app I can do that with the System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapDecoder class that it does not seem to exist in a Metro Win 8 app

```
Stream imageStreamSource = new FileStream(filetiff_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
TiffBitmapDecoder decoder = new TiffBitmapDecoder(imageStreamSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[indexPage];
```

Where indexPage is the number of the page that i want to be viewed.

Does anybody know a similar solution?

Comment: I found a solution to my own question... this link show the right code :-) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/92b8e90a-c155-4c87-b6b0-0db811fb5fa5/display-bitmapframe

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any experience with neither TiffBitmapDecoder nor Metro WPF, but I have used a similar thing before in WPF like this:

```
using (System.Drawing.Image imageFile = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("temp.tif"))
{
    System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension frameDimensions = new System.Drawing.Imaging.FrameDimension(imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);
    imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, indexPage);
    using (System.Drawing.Bitmap newImage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(imageFile.Size.Width, imageFile.Size.Height))
    {
        using (System.Drawing.Graphics gr = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
        {
            gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            gr.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            gr.DrawImage(imageFile, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), imageFile.Size));
        }
        //do whatever with the newImage bitmap
    }
}
```

SelectActiveFrame is the point you need there, so you can try that if it also works for you...

Comment: on a second thought, i saw that you may directly use imageFile as BitmapSource just after using SelectActiveFrame. I used like above because i was painting more bitmaps over this one :)